# Kubernetes app latency issue from india location gcp

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created kubernetes cluster in Europe region [europe-west2] and i have deployed simple app on it. I have configured nginx ingress to access the website. when i am accessing my website from India location, it is taking too much time to open (6 to 8 sec) while it's opening from europe within 300 to 500ms. i can't understand logic behind that,I don't have any heavy content on the website. i have also check latency of google provided by google (http://www.gcping.com/) and as per gcp ping check it should 353ms. Can anybody help me to resolve the latency issue of my site?

Comment: It's unclear from your question what you are measuring. Do you measure latency until the first byte or do you measure the time until your page is usable? Having a webpage that takes a lot of sequential requests to load will compound the network latency.

Comment: @LukasEichler  Yes, I am testing my webpage speed. It's taking time to load. I am checking speed latency from Pingdom and www.dotcom-tools.com/website-speed-test.aspx. It's taking 6 to 8 sec to open my webpage. I doesn't have any heavy content on my webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a chance to check [this](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tutorials/optimize-app-latency) GCP tutorial, on how to measure properly app latency depending on specific load balancer used ?

Worth to mention here, that your scenario falls into app with "HTTP(S)/TCP/SSL Proxy Load Balancing" category (GCE Ingress Controller creates HTTP Loadbalancer front-end for you Ingress -> Service -> Pod (Application))

You mentioned you use PING for testing your app latency, according to the GCP tutorial, a Time To First Byte (TTFB) method should be used with curl command, when testing HTTP request to Web servers (exact command to be found in the link I shared).

You may also use [Stackdriver Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/quickstart) to drill down to detailed latency data (on GKE workloads you need to use client libraries to generate them)

I hope this will help you to move further with this.